# Beginner - Do While loop and Smallest/Largest entry

Tags: java, do-while

I'm having a problem that I can't figure out, so I am posting my code for some help.   I am a beginner at this and have just addressed do-while loops, so have pity! :)  The assignment was to write an integer entry program that stored smallest and largest, took count of entries and terminated at an entry of -99.   I've found that if I enter some integers, the count is wrong, while others are right.   The data: 15, 30, 25, 20...  comes up as "You've entered 2 numbers".  Other entries come up correct.   I would greatly appreciate anyone telling me what I'm missing.

```
import java.util.Scanner;

public class LargestSmallest {
public static void main(String[] args)
{
    int entry, smaller=0, larger=0,count=0;
    boolean again=true;
    Scanner input = new Scanner(System.in);   

    do
    {System.out.print("Enter your integer: ");
        entry = input.nextInt();

        if (count==0 && entry !=-99)
        {
          larger = entry;
          smaller = entry;
          count +=1;
        }
        else 
        {             

          if (entry < smaller && entry!=-99 )
          {
              smaller = entry;
              count+=1;
          }
          else if (entry > larger && entry !=-99)
          {
              larger = entry;
              count+=1;
          }  
        }

           if (entry == -99)
           again = false;
     }
    while (again);

   if (count >1)
   {
    System.out.println("You entered "+count+" numbers.");
    System.out.println("Your smallest number is: "+ smaller);
    System.out.println("Your largest number is: "+larger);
   }
}
```

}

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Since you are incrementing the count only if the condition is satisfied,your count value wont be right if you dont get an entry smaller than the existing smallest or larger than the existing largest.

you have to change as folllows:

```
 else 
            {             

              if (entry < smaller && entry!=-99 )
              {
                  smaller = entry;

              }
              else if (entry > larger && entry !=-99)
              {
                  larger = entry;

              }
              count+=1;

            }

               if (entry == -99) {
               again = false;
               count --;
               }
```

Since you are checking the -99 condition only after the count has been incremented, if the user enters -99 , you have to decrease the counter by 1

Answer (score 1):

You are only incrementing `count` in cases where the smaller or larger numbers are updated. you need to take `count += 1;` out of the if statements and do it all the time.

Comment: Ok, I see.. so if the number satisfies neither criteria count is ignored.   I was originally doing that, but removed it to exclude the -99 criteria.  Thank you!